# Force low-resolution in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display

I'm developing my apps in **@2x**.

Sometimes I want to see what the design looks like on a low-resoultion device.
I've noticed that you can right-click apps, go to the Info panel, and check **Open in Low Resolution**.

[image]

However, it's not that easily accessible.
Is there an easier way to force the app to run in **@1x** from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open an App in Low-Resolution you need to change the following setting in Plist.

```
NSHighResolutionCapable = false
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: In my tests setting this to false had no effect. The documentation only mentions setting it to true. Asked about that at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426140/how-to-enable-use-low-resolution-on-retina-display-for-an-application-when-shi